# Java untyped generic classes, removing their functions generics types

Tags: java, generics, foreach, iterable, raw-types

Ok Question about javas generics, iterable, and for-each loop.  The problem being that, if I declare my 'Test' class untyped,  I lose all generic information on all my functions and for-each is not likeing that at all.

Example

```
public class Test<T> implements Iterable<Integer>{

    public Test() {}

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {return null;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();

        //Good,
        //its returning an Iterator<object> but it automatically changes to  Iterator<Integer>
        Iterator<Integer> it = t.iterator();

        //Bad
        //incompatable types, required Integer, found Object
        for(Integer i : t){
        }
    }Untyped generic classes losing 
}
```

When 'Test t' is untyped, the 'iterator()' function returns 'iterator' instead of a 'iterator < Integer >'.

I'm not exactly sure for the reason behind it, I know a fix for that is just use a wild card on 'Test < ? > t = new test()'.  However this is a less than ideal solution.
Is their any way to only edit the class declaration and its functions and have the for each loop work untyped?

Comment: If you use raw types, generics on methods will be ignored (see latest Java Puzzlers instalment). Don't use raw types. Recent versions of javac should give warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the video link, very interesting stuff in their.  The reasoning behind the <?>  makes sence now.

Answer (score 3):

You should just do the following:

```
public class Test implements Iterable<Integer>{
```

Remove the generic type all together.

Your `Test` class is not generic at all.  It is simply implementing a generic interface.  Declaring a generic type is not necessary.  This will also have the benefit of remove that generic warning you were getting.

[@Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444087/java-untyped-generic-classes-removing-their-functions-generics-types/4444197#4444197) makes a good point.  If you actually wanted a generic `Test` type, you should declare `Test` as a generic iterator:

You should just do the following:

```
public class Test implements Iterable<Integer>{
```

Remove the generic type all together.

Your `Test` class is not generic at all.  It is simply implementing a generic interface.  Declaring a generic type is not necessary.  This will also have the benefit of remove that generic warning you were getting.

```
public class Test<T> implements Iterable<T>{
```

And then, make sure you make `Test` generic when you instantiate it.

```
Test<Integer> t = new Test<Integer>;
```

Then calls to `for(Integer i: t)` will compile.

Answer (score 2):

You should either write this:

```
public class Test implements Iterable<Integer>{
  ...
```

or actually generify your class:

```
public class Test<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {return null;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> t = new Test<Integer>();

        Iterator<Integer> it = t.iterator();

        for(Integer i : t){
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just what I was starting to write. +1

Comment: Yup that would work, but you can run into situations like. "public class Vertex<T> implements Iterable<Edge<T>>".  For a graph example.  It is odd but you can get the situation where your iterable does not return the class that calls it.  My fault I poorly explained it.

Comment: That's completely different question. In that case your iterator() method would have to return Iterator<Edge<T>>, as simple as that. On the other hand, you likely don't need to clarify your Iterable implementation and can just declare it more generic as implements Iterable<T> instead of Iterable<Edge<T>>.